# ECDSA sign test vectors

Tags: dsa, test-vectors

I've seen [a large set of ECDSA test vectors](https://github.com/google/wycheproof) for verification. In addition, I've seen some test vectors from NIST, and those [can be found here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979).

Is anyone aware of ECDSA *sign* test vectors which, if "deterministic k" is used, where the algorithm in RFC 6979 produces a "not suitable k" (leading to rarely used code paths)? Please see below.

- `= 0` (or `= 1`)
- `> g` (or `n`, the group order)
- where the signature computation leads to `r = 0`
- where the signature computation leads to `s = 0`

Comment: I believe there isn't such test vector, because the popular hash functions made it almost impossible for those code paths to be reached. You best hope would be to construct a "debugger-controlled" hash function that output desired hash value to trigger those edge cases.

Comment: Unfortunately so called edge cases are hardly ever tested well enough in the field of cryptography, it's one of my pet peeves. Besides that, I've seen many tests where only the algorithm / protocol level tests are performed, not implementation level tests. Software may have *internal* edge cases as well.